# visual studio making characters move using classes and not picture boxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

im trying to make character move in VS without picture boxes, i seem to be getting close but when i tried to put in the key presses there is a red line under the key of key.keycodes and a red line under my public enum direction and i dont know why. here is my code, it isnt fully  complete but you will probably get the idea. so what im asking in a nutshell is why cant i put in keycodes and why is my enum directional code underlined.

```
public enum Direction { Up, Right, Down, Left }
public class Cat
{
    public Direction currentDirection = Direction.Up;
    public PictureBox CatImage = new PictureBox();
    public int mouseSize = 25;

    public int maxScreenX;
    public int maxScreenY;

    private ImageList CatImages = new ImageList();

    public Cat(Form formInstance)
    {
        maxScreenX = formInstance.Width - 50;
        maxScreenY = formInstance.Height - 80;


        // start with mouse in the centre of the screen
        CatImage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(maxScreenX / 2, maxScreenY / 2);

        // we'll add the mouse images
        CatImages.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.catUp);
        CatImages.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.catRight);
        CatImages.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.catDown);
        CatImages.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.catLeft);

        formInstance.Controls.Add(CatImage);
        CatImage.BringToFront();
    }

    public void MoveMouse()
    {



        if (!canMove)
        {



        }

        // Change the mouse image to match the new direction
        CatImage.Image = CatImages.Images[(int)currentDirection];

        if (canMove)
        {


            if (key.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                CatImage.Top -= 5;
            }
            if (key.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                CatImage.Top += 5;
            }
            if (key.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                CatImage.Left -= 5;
            }
            if (key.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                CatImage.Left += 5;
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You use the word `key` in your code like it is something. But it is nothing (i.e., it is nowhere declared or defined what that omnious `key` is. It is also not some keyword or known type provided by the .NET framework libraries). So VS draws the red lines there, telling you "*i don't know what that mysterious word 'key' stands for*". Not sure about the Enum though. When you hover with the mouse over the red line, a tooltip should appear, explaining more in detail what VS thinks is wrong with your usage of your Enum...

Comment: If Visual Studio is highlighting a problem in your code, you should be able to mouse over that and get a popup with the actual error message (or go to View..Error List).  Those may tell you what you need to know (and if they don't, you should include them here for others to help you)

Comment: You might want to look into the documentation for KeyDown or KeyPress events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/using-keyboard-events) to see examples of how to process or react to keyboard presses in your WinForms program. (You might also look here when you want to process keyboard events at the form level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level)